# Cross domain XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

I am trying to execute an XSS inside the `<iframe>` that I am invoking in my website/browser for another legitimate website.

Here is what I have worked around though,**which doesn't work.**

```
<iframe src="legitwebsite.com" id="targetFrame" onmouseover="document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.alert(document.location.href);">
```

I don't know if this is workable or not, but I believe that if a website has clickjacking vulnerability, then it can probably be escalated to an XSS even on non-sensitive pages using this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: does it trigger anything?

Comment: All it triggers is the parent domain's `document.domain.href`.

Comment: Is not about your code, is about the website `legitwebsite.com` not allow your access, so your browser blocked this.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I believe CORS headers only work for XHR, not iframes

Comment: @MartinZeitler, CORS is not the issue here.

Comment: @yip102011, as I mentioned, `if a website is vulnerable to clickjacking` meaning, I have already considered your scenario of `X-Frame-Options`

Comment: meant `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://..`. there's also `DENY` & `SAMEORIGIN`.

Comment: What is the question here? If this markup is in a document whose origin is not `legitwebsite.com` then you won't be able to access `targetFrame.contentWindow`, whatever the headers or whatelse you may dream of. Only ways are `targetFrame.postMessage()` and `<iframe src="/myproxy?url=legitwebsite.com"></iframe>`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler these CSP rules can only make the security stronger, never leverage it.

Comment: @Kaiido `ALLOW-FROM *` would permit embedding everywhere ...it's just the question how a browser interprets no such header being sent out... also Chrome extensions can inject script just everywhere.

Comment: @MartinZeitler which is the default... The question here is not about embedding (i.e displaying the content) but access it from script (i.e break the Same-Origin-Policies). And if you are from within `chrome://` script then, yes, you can just screen record anything and copy-transfer all the disk content...

Comment: @Kaiido, can you explain how can I create injection with targetFrame.postMessage()?

Comment: You don't do injection, you send a message. The other document has to be listening to it. e.g in *abroad.html* `onmessage = e => console.log('got message', e.data);` in *local.html* `targetFrame.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');` then *abroad.html*'s console will output `"got message" "hello"`. [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).